# robot don't try to match it's real position

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The navigation stack was running quite well in navigation stage with my navigation config file.
From my understanding, the robot will try to match it's real position gradually, as long as it move around.
But, in my physical robot, the robot don't try to match it's real position, when i give it a goal. The tf tree is OK. What is the problem maybe?

In addition, I can use my robot to built a good map. Does that means my odometry data is sensible ?

[image description http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Eustccm/frame.png](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Eustccm/frame.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9876/robot-don%27t-try-to-match-it%27s-real-position/) by [Charles](https://answers.ros.org/users/333/charles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Charles](https://answers.ros.org/users/333/charles/) on 2011-05-03**:
It seems that AMCL didn't work, but the /map frame to /odom frame transformation was OK.

**Comment by [Charles](https://answers.ros.org/users/333/charles/) on 2011-05-03**:
I have set the initialpose. I can use rviz to set the initialpose and send a goal to the robot. The robot move to the goal, when i give it a goal. But the laser scan line don't try to match the walls and the corners automatically.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-03**:
What does it actually do when you give it a goal? Does it attempt to move at all? Does it just sit? Does move_base throw any errors to the terminal window or rxconsole? Did you write your own drivers for the physical robot or are you using existing drivers such as p2os?

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-05-03**:
Have you set the initialpose for your robot manually for AMCL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried joysticking the robot around with AMCL running to see if you can get reasonable results independent of navigation? Have you been careful to set an initialpose that is close to the actual position of the robot in the map? Have you verified your odometry and laser scans are reasonable?

The [navigation tuning guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide) gives some tips on how you might check your odometry is working.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1